# Compare list1 objects against the entire list2 objects for the output of non-intersecting CIDRs using python ipaddr library

Tags: python

```
# GOAL: Compare list1 objects against the entire list2 objects for the output of non-intersecting CIDRs and output CIDRs that do NOT intersect
#
# example: item #1 in list1 gets checked against all entries in list2 for non-intersecting CIDRs
# then item #2 in list1 gets checked against all entries in list2 for non-intersecting CIDRs
# then item #3 in list1 gets checked against all entries in list2 for non-intersecting CIDRs
# output any in CIDRs in list1 that do NOT intersect any item in any CIDR from list2

# list1 and list2 are literally 2 files of which both contain tons of IPs with their CIDR range
# Need to check for any list1 items intersecting IPs with any of list 2 items

# Servers as loop counters and the lines contained in list1
list1_counter = 0
# Servers as loop counters and the lines contained in list2
list2_counter = 0

# collect results from CIDR check
results = []

# loop until at the line count of line2 as it reached the end of list
while list1_counter <= list2_cidr_count:
    
    # for list1's first line compared to all of list2 lines
    for list1_lines[list1_counter] in list2_lines:
        print(list1_lines[list1_counter])
        print(list2_lines[list2_counter])
        
        # Compare CIDR for any intersections for list1's first line to all of list2 lines
        a = (ipaddr.IPNetwork(list1_lines[list1_counter]).overlaps(list2_lines[list2_counter]))
        
        # append to results list here
        results.append(a)
        
        # increase counter to go to list1's second line and start from top
        list2_counter += 1
```

New to python and lost in logic. Does anyone have an example I can use or just knows how to iterate this with the counters the correct way? I'm almost thinking I need a nested statement to work but it fails in many different ways each time I try.

Appreciate any insight I can get!

Comment: Sry, but your code is broken in so many ways that i am completely lost in trying to understand what you want to acchieve.

Comment: Why is your homework assigning you to work with a [deprecated Python 2 library](https://pypi.org/project/ipaddr/)? Also if you're working with Python2, please mention that in the question-body and tags!

Comment: @H.Doebler Sorry. I added detailed comments now and a small edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me when I was starting out writing code, creating loops and flow-control was writing down what I wanted to do in basic English before beginning to code.

So, if we simplify the instructions in your code, and skip the part about CIDRs, then we can write it down as the following:

We have two lists:

- list1
- list2

**For** each **value** **inside** of **list1**, we want to **go over** each **value** **inside** of **list2** and **compare them to each other**.

**If** the **current value** of **list1** is **found inside** of **list2**, then we want to **discard** that **value**. However, **if no matches were found**, then we want to **save** that **value**.

Okay, so now we can create a simpler example with the above statements as the scaffold of our loops and comparisons:

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list2 = [1,3,5,7,9]

# A variable that holds all values we want to save.
saved_values = []
# loop over each value of list1
for value in list1:
    not_in_list2 = True
    # For every value inside of list1,
    # we go over list2's values, one by one in a loop
    for other_value in list2:
        # if the comparison is true,
        # then we set the variable "not_in_list2" to False
        if value == other_value:
            not_in_list2 = False
    
    # If all of the comparisons inside of the list2-loop
    # was False then the variable never changed,
    # and we can add the variable to our saved_values list.
    if not_in_list2:
        saved_values.append(value)
    
# Finally, we print out the saved_values variable
print(saved_values)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

You should now have the building blocks to finish your program.

Comment: Thank you for an example! I'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: I was able to do exactly what I wanted with your example so thank you so much!